# JS operators in string sent through AJAX causing request to fail

Tags: jquery, ajax, string, post, operators

I have made a password manager but the passwords aren't picked up fully if it contains any kind of javascript operator. I want to make an AJAX call, but if my string from my input field contains a `+` or any other operator the string just stops. How can I ignore the operators is the strings?

```js
if ($("#editpswform").data("changed")) {
  id = $('#passid').text();
  name = $('#pswname').val();
  url = $('#pswurla').text();
  username = $('#pswusr').val();
  password = $('#pswi').val();
  notes = $('#pswnotes').val();
  var dataString = 'EditPSW=true' + '&id=' + id + '&name=' + name + '&url=' + url + '&username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&notes=' + notes;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "utils.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
      $.ajax({
        url: "utils.php?setsession=Password saved!"
      }).done(function() {
        load_data();

        function load_data(query) {
          $.ajax({
            url: "search.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
              query: query
            },
            success: function(data) {
              $('#contentmain').html(data);
            }
          });
        }

        OpenNotification();
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "utils.php?setsession=Error saving password!",
      }).done(function() {
        OpenNotification();
      });
    }
  });
} else {
  $.ajax({
    url: "utils.php?setsession=No changes made!",
  }).done(function() {
    OpenNotification();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem sounds like an issue with the encoding of the values within the querystring. Send the values in an object instead. This way you avoid the ugly concatenation logic, and jQuery will encode the values for you properly.

```
var dataString = {
  EditPSW: true,
  id: id,
  name: name,
  url: url,
  username: username,
  password: password,
  notes: notes
}
```

Comment: The same way as you normally would `$_POST['key']`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to encode each value in the URL. Like this:

`var dataString = 'EditPSW=true' + '&id=' + encodeURIComponent(id) + '&name=' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '&url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&username=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(password) + '&notes=' + encodeURIComponent(notes);`

Comment: Is this data than usable is php?

Comment: Why not just use `encodeURI()` instead of hacking together one massive string with multiple concatenations and calls to the same method?

Comment: `encodeURI` would also encode the `&`, which should not be urlencoded. I'm not opposed to your solution, by the way.

Comment: both of your awnsers do work, but is one method faster than the other?

Comment: I guess encodeURIComponent() takes longer to process

Comment: There's no real performance difference, it's just that this method produces needlessly ugly code.

Comment: Ah okay, that's true the object looks much cleaner